# How to know Package Name of a Top running app from my service running in background (android)

Tags: android, android-activity, service, android-package-managers

How can i know the package name of top Running application.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2p4iuj7dj7zv5u4/Screenshot%20%28234%29.png

(in the link , above application is temple run 2 and package is com.imangi.templerun2 )

I need to retrieve the package name(ie com.imangi.templerun2) from my service and store it in String named packageName .
How can i do it ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 // Return a list of the tasks that are currently running,
 // with the most recent being first and older ones after in order.
 // Taken 1 inside getRunningTasks method means want to take only
 // top activity from stack and forgot the olders.
 List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

 ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
 componentInfo.getPackageName(); // here it is
```

Comment: Its returning my services package name tried am.getRunningTasks(2)- am.getRunningTasks(7) every time my package name.

Comment: it will return your package name, if you are in your application. Run this code in background service, and check package name every second for example. Print package name to log. Run your application, press Home, run another application, open logs and check package name.